# Add days to a date and insert added date in table for SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, date-difference

> @Rdatetime ='2017-04-18 11:49:38.633'
>
> @Date to add = 2
>
> @Output = '2017-04-20 11:49:38.633'

Hi all,
This is my Problem , i am getting Rdatetime and date to be added in another table . i have yo add the date and save it in datetime format

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATEADD built in function :

```
 DECLARE @Rdatetime DATETIME ='2017-04-18 11:49:38.633'

 DECLARE @Date INT = 2

 DECLARE @Output DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,@Date,@Rdatetime)

 SELECT @Output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use `DATEADD` function by giving `D` as the first parameter.Then the number of days you want to add and the date to which you want to add.

```
SET @Output=DATEADD(D,@Date,@Rdatetime)
```