# Substitute interval 1 day to SQL server syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, hana

I have this datetime, working in Hana:

```
CAST((B."ZFBDT" + B."ZBD1T" * INTERVAL '1 day') AS DATE) + CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME)
```

```
B."ZFBDT" = '2020-10-30'
B."ZBD1T" = 67
RES = 2021-01-05 23:59:59
```

The problem is that I need to convert it into SQL Server, and I now that INTERVAL is not supported. Actually I don't even understand the syntax properly: why they are multipling for INTERVAL 1 day?

I could unserstand adding or subtracting, but why multipling?
Anyway, how can I make this work in SQL Server?

Thanks

Comment: [DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: What are the values of `B."ZFBDT"` and `B."ZBD1T"` and what result of the expression do you get with these values? [Edit] the question and include that information.

Comment: @stickybit you're right, done

Comment: To answer your question about the multiplication, it's because you want to add 67 days. There isn't a 67 days `INTERVAL` but you *can* have 67 1 day `INTERVAL`s, which is what `B."ZBD1T" * INTERVAL '1 day'` is doing.

Comment: @Larnu I've tried on Hana with and without the * INTERVAL '1 day' and the results are the same for every row, there are no cases with differences, so I still don't understand why it is useful

Comment: Presumably Hana permits the `{date and time} + {integer}` syntax then, @Federicofkt . SQL Server also permits `{(small)datetime} + {int}` syntax, however, as the new date and time data types don't then this can result in bad habits. In truth, many are of the opinion that it's best to *not* treat date and times like numbers, and treat them as what they are; dates and times. I, personally, am of this opinion. If you therefore want to add a day, second, etc, to that date and time, you use the explicit syntax to do so, not implicit conversion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to a date and insert added date in table for SQL SERVER 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465023/add-days-to-a-date-and-insert-added-date-in-table-for-sql-server-2012)

Comment: Let's not get into the fact that `23:59:59` is probably being used as the inclusive end of a range, which excludes `23:59:59.3` and `23:59:59.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SQL Server you may try the following:

```sql
DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, B.ZBD1T + 1 , CAST(B.ZFBDT AS datetime)))
```

You may phrase your problem as wanting to add `B.ZBD1T` days to the input date `B.ZFBDT`, and then place the resulting timestamp at 23:59:59, i.e. one second before midnight.  We can achieve that by adding `B.ZBD1T` plus one days, then subtracting one second to get the 23:59:59 time component.

Comment: Probably worth noting, now, that the above does assume that `B.ZFBDT` is a `datetime` or `smalldatetime`, as syntax like `{datetime2} + {int}` doesn't work. You would likely be better off moving the `+ 1` to the *number* parameter, as then the above would work for all the date *and* time data types, but obviously not the `date` and `time` data types.

Comment: This explicitly won't work on a `date`, Tim; `date` has no time portion so you can't subtract seconds from it.

Comment: after clarification, it looks like ZFBDT should be converted to datetime instead.

Comment: Or perhaps a `datetime2(0)`.